# Detailed Skype for Business reports from Microsoft Graph

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, skype-for-business

my goal is simple: I want to fetch a detailed report of the PSTN usage of my users in Office 365.  I wanted to achieve that with PowerShell but unfortunately, the `Get-CxPSTNUsageDetailReport` command was deprecated in January 2018.

I ended up playing around Microsoft Graph as [suggested by this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/reporting/Get-CsPSTNUsageDetailReport?view=exchange-ps) (the one about the deprecated command). After taking a deep look in here, I wasn't able to find any information on how to get this report from the API.

Do any of you knows if there is:

1. An API query for that
2. An official support channel for this

Also, I've found some threads about Skype for Business and most of them were back from 2017 stating that a lot of S4B features were not available in Graph, is it still the case?

If so, why are they suggesting Microsoft Graph as an alternative then?

Comment: There is a pretty good article on using Graph from PowerShell at https://itfordummies.net/2017/07/04/microsoft-graph-api-powershell/

Answer (score 1):

You can use this API:

```
/reports/SfbActivity(view=view-value, period=period-value, date=date-value)/content
```

For more information, refer to the [documentation](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/reportroot_sfbactivity).